# How to add Entity in Category.cs class in nopCommerce?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing, nopcommerce, developer-tools

I want to add Entity CategoryType in Category Table in nopCommerce. For this implementation, I follow [nopCommerce/developer tutorial](https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/developer/tutorials/update-existing-entity.html) and implemented according to this link.

Step 1: I added new field CategoryType in Nop.Core.Domain.Category.cs class.

```cs
namespace Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a category
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Category : BaseEntity, ILocalizedEntity, ISlugSupported, IAclSupported, IStoreMappingSupported, IDiscountSupported<DiscountCategoryMapping>, ISoftDeletedEntity
    {
        public string CategoryType { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the description
        /// </summary>
    }
}
```

Step 2: I map CategoryType column in mapper class in Nop.Data.Mapping.Builders.Catalog CategoryBuilder.cs class as described below:

```cs
public override void MapEntity(CreateTableExpressionBuilder table)
{
    table
        .WithColumn(nameof(Category.CategoryType)).AsString(400).NotNullable()
        .WithColumn(nameof(Category.Name)).AsString(400).NotNullable()
        .WithColumn(nameof(Category.MetaKeywords)).AsString(400).Nullable()
        .WithColumn(nameof(Category.MetaTitle)).AsString(400).Nullable()
        .WithColumn(nameof(Category.PageSizeOptions)).AsString(200).Nullable();
}
```

Step 3: Now I also create migration class for migrate new column into category Table.
For this I designed new class named AddCategoryType.cs in Namespace  Nop.Data.Migrations:

```cs
public class AddCategoryType : AutoReversingMigration
{
    //Add migration for Add Category Type in Category table.
    public override void Up()
    {
        Create.Column(nameof(Category.CategoryType))
         .OnTable(nameof(Category))
         .AsString(255)
         .Nullable();
    }
}
```

Step 4: The validator class is used to validate the data stored inside of the model class
For apply validation I added class CategoryValidator.cs in namespace Nop.Web.Areas.Admin.Validators.Catalog:

```cs
public partial class CategoryValidator : BaseNopValidator<CategoryModel>
{
    public CategoryValidator(ILocalizationService localizationService, IMappingEntityAccessor mappingEntityAccessor)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.CategoryType).Length(0, 255);
        RuleFor(x => x.CategoryType).NotEmpty().WithMessageAwait(localizationService.GetResourceAsync("Admin.Catalog.Categories.Fields.CategoryType.Required"));
    }
}
```

Step 5: I added CateoryType Column in View side. For this I added CategoryType column in CategoryModel.cs class in namespace `Nop.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.Catalog`:

```cs
public partial record CategoryModel 
{
    [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Categories.Fields.CategoryType")]
    public string CategoryType { get; set; }
}
```

Step 6: Now I make changes in View for display this new added Column in class _CreateOrUpdate.Info.cshtml in namespace nop.Web.Areas.Admin.Views.Category:

```cs
nop.Web.Areas.Admin.Views.Category._CreateOrUpdate.Info.cshtml

@model CategoryModel

<div class="card-body">
    @(await Html.LocalizedEditorAsync<CategoryModel, CategoryLocalizedModel>("category-name-localized",
        @<div>
<div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <nop-label asp-for="CategoryType" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <nop-editor asp-for="CategoryType" asp-required="true" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CategoryType"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <nop-label asp-for="Description" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <nop-editor asp-for="Description" asp-template="RichEditor" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>))
</div>
```

This code I implemented not create CategoryType in Category Table and displaying error in output: **An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Invalid column name 'CategoryType'.**

Comment: Are you sure the column was created in the table? Your code for `AddCategoryType` doesn't have the `nopMigration` attribute.